# How can I add an view on top of a UIPopoverController containing a UINavigationController?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, uipopovercontroller

EDIT:  I answered my own question below.

I've got a UIPopoverController that has a UINavigationController set as its contentViewController.  When the nav controller's root view controller loads, it needs to pull some data in.  I want to put a semi-transparent view over the entire popover that says "loading", but can't seem to find a way to add it to the entire thing.

I've tried adding it to the nav controller's UINavigationBar (and changing the bar's clip subviews and autoresize subviews to NO), but the view is only visible on the bar (it seems to clip it anyway).

If I add it to the view of the root view controller of the nav controller, it only shows up there and not on the bar.

Any ideas of how I can accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

There are some nice 3rd party libraries out there that assist with loading data in the background and informing the user.

The site http://cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls is very useful and saves you reinventing the wheel.

For your problem I would checkout https://github.com/jdg/MBProgressHUD and see if that is what you're after.

Comment: Thanks for the response - cocoacontrols is a cool resource!  Unfortunately the reason I want to find how to fully cover a popover is so that I can easily cover (and thus disable) any controls on the navigation bar inside the popover.

Answer (score 0):

I swear I tried this, but now it's working by adding the "loading" view to the navigation controller's view itself.  Works perfectly!  :)